# Counting the numnber of (labelled and unlabelled) rooted trees on $n$ vertices with height $h$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, trees

As far as I know, the number of labelled rooted trees on $n$ vertices is $n^{n-1}$. Is there a known result for counting the number of (labelled and unlabelled) rooted trees on $n$ vertices having height $h$? Note that these trees need not be binary. Also, I am looking for a closed form answer if possible, which will likely be a function of $n$ and $h$. In the worst case, I would like to know the asymptotic amount if an exact result isn't known.

Comment: If you’re talking about height, you need rooted trees; there are $n^{n-1}$ labelled rooted trees on $n$ vertices.

Comment: I've edited my question with additional information. Why is the number of trees of a certain height equal to the number of rooted trees?

Comment: The height of a tree is the length of the longest branch from the root to a leaf; the notion is undefined unless the tree is rooted.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the question  by the OP asking  for a reference I will  try to do
just that, providing  links to the OEIS. Surprisingly  enough even the
OEIS does not  offer the usual variety of  references here, suggesting
that  this problem is  open. We  compute generating  functions $T_{\le
h}(z)$ for the height being at  most $h$ and the desired count is then
given by $T_{\le h}(z)-T_{\le h-1}(z).$

We have for the labeled the combinatorial class
$$\mathcal{T}_{\le h} = 
\mathcal{Z}\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T}_{\le h-1}).$$

For the labeled case this translates into 
$$T_{\le h}(z) = z\exp T_{\le h-1}(z)$$

with $T_{\le 0}(z) = 0$ and $T_{\le 1}(z) = z.$

For example with $h=3$ we get 
$$T_{\le 3}(z) = z \exp(z \exp(z))$$

which yields the sequence [OEIS A052512](https://oeis.org/A052512):

$$1, 2, 9, 40, 205, 1176, 7399, 50576, \ldots$$

and for $h=4$ we get

$$T_{\le 4}(z) = z(\exp( z \exp(z \exp(z)))$$

which yields the sequence [OEIS A052513](https://oeis.org/A052513):

$$1, 2, 9, 64, 505, 4536, 46249, 526352, \ldots$$

We have for the unlabeled the combinatorial class
$$\mathcal{T}_{\le h} = 
\mathcal{Z}\times \textsc{MSET}(\mathcal{T}_{\le h-1}).$$

which translates into generating functions, as follows,
$$T_{\le h}(z) = z\exp 
\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} 
\frac{T_{\le h-1}(z^l)}{l}\right).$$

where $T_{\le 0}(z) = 0$ and $T_{\le 1}(z) = z$ as before.

We get for

$$T_{\le 2}(z) =
z\exp \left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{z^l}{l}\right)
= z\exp\log\frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{z}{1-z}.$$

These are root nodes with singletons attached to them.
Continuing with the recursion we obtain

$$T_{\le 3}(z) = z\exp 
\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} 
\frac{1}{l}\sum_{q\ge 1} z^{ql}\right)
= z\exp 
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} 
\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{1}{l} z^{ql}\right)
\\ = z\exp\sum_{q\ge 1}\log\frac{1}{1-z^q}
= z \prod_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{1-z^q}.$$

which yields the sequence [OEIS A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041):

$$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22, 30, 42, 56, \ldots$$

(partition numbers, not surprisingly, as  we allocate one node for the
root and the rest is a partition into singleton fans of height at most
two, of which there is only one per node count).

From $T_{\le 4}(z)$ we obtain the sequence
[OEIS A001383](https://oeis.org/A001383):

$$1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 29, 53, 98, 177, 319, 565, \ldots$$

Finally $T_{\le 5}(z)$ yields the sequence
[OEIS A001384](https://oeis.org/A001384):

$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 19, 42, 89, 191, 402, 847 \ldots$$

There are two interpretations  here depending on whether the singleton
is supposed to have height zero or one. A relevant link is this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183643/).

**Remark.** The  complexity of the growth of  the partition numbers
provides  an idea  of  the difficulty  of  this problem,  which is  as
difficult if  not more.  Studying the OEIS  entries in more  detail it
does appear that simple recurrences for these can be computed.

Concerning  the  recurrence for  the  labeled case  differentiation
produces

$$T'_{\le h}(z) = \exp T_{\le h-1}(z) +
z \exp T_{\le h-1}(z) \times T'_{\le h-1}(z)
\\ = \frac{1}{z} T_{\le h}(z) + T_{\le h}(z) \times T'_{\le h-1}(z).$$

Extracting coefficients here we get

$$n! [z^n] T'_{\le h}(z)
=  T_{\le h, n+1} = n! [z^{n+1}] T_{\le h}(z)
+ n! [z^n ] T_{\le h}(z) \times T'_{\le h-1}(z)
\\ = \frac{1}{n+1} T_{\le h, n+1}
+ n! \sum_{q=1}^{n} [z^q] T_{\le h}(z) [z^{n-q}] T'_{\le h-1}(z)
\\ = \frac{1}{n+1} T_{\le h, n+1}
+ \sum_{q=1}^{n} {n\choose q} T_{\le h,q} T_{\le h-1, n-q+1}.$$

We obtain the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{T_{\le h, n+1} = \frac{n+1}{n} 
\sum_{q=1}^{n} {n\choose q} T_{\le h,q} T_{\le h-1, n-q+1}.}$$

The boundary condition here is $T_{\le h, 1} = 1$ and
$T_{0,1} = 0.$

Applying differentiation to the unlabeled case yields

$$T'_{\le h}(z) = 
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T_{\le h-1}(z^l)}{l}\right)
\\ + z\exp \left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T_{\le h-1}(z^l)}{l}\right)
\times \sum_{l\ge 1} T'_{\le h-1}(z^l) z^{l-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{z} T_{\le h}(z)
+ T_{\le h}(z) \times \sum_{l\ge 1} T'_{\le h-1}(z^l) z^{l-1}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$[z^n] T'_{\le h}(z) = (n+1) T_{\le h, n+1}
\\ = [z^{n+1}] T_{\le h}(z)
+ \sum_{l=1}^n 
\sum_{q=1}^n 
[z^q] T_{\le h}(z) [z^{n-q}] z^{l-1} T'_{\le h-1}(z^l)
\\ = T_{\le h, n+1}
+ \sum_{l=1}^n 
\sum_{q=1}^n 
T_{\le h,q} [z^{n-q-l+1}] T'_{\le h-1}(z^l).$$

We obtain the closed form

$$T_{\le h, n+1} = 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n 
\sum_{q=1}^n 
T_{\le h,q} [[l|n-q+1]] ((n-q+1)/l) T_{\le h-1, (n-q+1)/l}$$

which simplifies to

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{T_{\le h, n+1} = 
\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{q=1}^n \sum_{l|n-q+1}
T_{\le h,q} ((n-q+1)/l) T_{\le h-1, (n-q+1)/l}.}$$

Boundary conditions are the same as in the labeled case.

This  recurrence makes it  possible to  compute e.g.  $T_{\le 6,n}$
which yields

$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 47, 108, 252, 582, 
\\ 1345, 3086, 7072, 16121,\ldots$$

which is [OEIS A001385](https://oeis.org/A001385) and $T_{\le 7,n}$
which yields

$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 48, 114, 278, 676, 
\\ 1653, 4027, 9816, 23843,\ldots$$

which is [OEIS A034823](https://oeis.org/A034823).

The Maple code to implement these two recurrences is as follows.

```
T :=
proc(h,m)
option remember;
local n;

    if m=1 then if h=0 then return 0 else return 1 fi fi;

    n := m-1;

    (n+1)/n*
    add(binomial(n,q)*T(h,q)*T(h-1,n-q+1), q=1..n);
end;


X :=
proc(h,m)
option remember;
local n;

    if m=1 then if h=0 then return 0 else return 1 fi fi;

    n := m-1;

    1/n*
    add(add(X(h,q)*
            `if`(n-q+1 mod l =0, (n-q+1)/l*X(h-1,(n-q+1)/l), 0),
            q=1..n), l=1..n);

end;
```

Comment: Hey Marko, thanks for the very clear explanation. I wonder whether one can derive an asymptotic formula for the number of trees of height $h$ and $n$ nodes from your work ? I am not very familiar with this branch of combinatorics so I wouldn't know where to start.