# Counting rooted / unrooted trees / graphs on $n$ vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I came to know that number of labelled unrooted trees on $n$ vertices is given by formula $n^{n-2}$. Also, I came to know that there is [no closed formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2080797/336409) for number of unlabelled graphs on $n$ vertices. I have following doubts:

1. What is number of unlabelled unrooted trees?
2. What is number of unlabelled rooted trees?
3. What does it mean by tree in "labelled unrooted tree"? Does it mean graph connected with $n-1$ edges? Since I cannot imagine a tree without a root.
4. Also I believe there is no such thing as labelled / unlabelled "unrooted m-ary" tree, since for being m-ary, there has to be some root. Am I correct with this? If no, then how we can have unrooted m-ary tree and what is count of such trees on $n$ vertices? (Number of unlabelled rooted m-ary tree is given by Cayley's number $\frac{1}{(m-1)n+1}\binom{mn}{n}\times n!$)

Comment: An unrooted tree simply does not have a vertex designated as the root.  It's just a connected acyclic graph, or as you say, a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges.

Comment: Great, that confirms my 3rd doubt. Can you please help with other. Is count of unlabelled rooted trees (Q2) unknown as per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1801475/336409) answer? Also, I believe, that answer does not give count of labelled rooted trees, which I guess is $n^{n-1}$, right?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I wouldn't expect a closed-form formula for unlabeled trees.  Once you don't have labels, you have to take isomorphisms into account.  The number of labeled rooted trees is $n^{n-1}$ since for each unrooted tree, there are $n$ ways to choose the root.